# Bad UDP performance in Golang vs. Python

Tags: python, go, networking, udp

I want to send as many UDP packets as fast as possible. I tried different methods of sending UDP data in the [net](https://golang.org/pkg/net/?m=all) package, but ended up with the following;

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < THREADS; i++ {
        go loopSendHello()
    }

    // Sleep forever
    <-make(chan bool, 1)
}

func loopSendHello() {
    for {
        sendHello()
    }
}

func sendHello() {
    // Setup conn
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        IP:   net.IP{192, 168, 1, xxx},
        Port: 1337,
    }
    conn, err := net.ListenPacket("udp", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen:", err)
    }

    n, err := conn.WriteTo([]byte("hello"), &addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error while writing to conn! :", err)
    }

    conn.Close()
}
```

THREADS is defined by runtime.NumCPU() btw.
Benchmarking this using Wireshark gives these results:
[image: Golang benchmark]
About 90ms delay (if I'm reading this right).

While this is the situation in Python (this function is running in 4 threads):

```
def sendHello():
    while True:
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            addr = ("192.168.1.xxx", 1337)
            s.sendto(data, addr)
        except:
            print("error")
```

Benchmark using Wireshark: [image: py bench]. This is from 1ms to about 10ms delay! Insane differences.

How can I match python's speed in Go?

Comment: This is a pointless comparison, since in a normal program you would not be creating a new socket each time you want to send a single packet, especially if performance is a concern, so runtimes are not optimized for this. A 10ms delay is is also quite poor if you're looking for performance. In Go you should be using `ListenUDP` and `WriteToUDP` for something more comparable, and you're also not closing the socket in python.

Comment: @JimB creating only one connection which is passed on to all created goroutines, and using ListenUDP/WriteToUDP gives a result of 100ms delay. This is worse performance than the original situation.

Comment: Update: The performance is not worse but is about the same as before, my bad.

Comment: You must have something else going on, but we have no way of knowing without a [mcve]. My laptop for example can generate 250k packets per second. It also doesn't do you any good to have multiple goroutines sending from the same socket. The interface can only write packets so fast, so increasing contention on that doesn't improve performance.

Comment: @JimB Hmm that might be, but I've tested on my macbook with similar results, where Go performs very badly. Anyhow, it seems like Rust solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

So I decided to very quickly create a simple benchmark of sending 200 000 UDP packets without any threads or bad programming techniques. The benchmark is between Go and Python. In addition I wanted a benchmark test to be concidered close to as fast as possible. I concidered using C, but as I'm on Windows it seemed easiest to use Rust.

Rust code:

```
use std::time::{SystemTime};
use std::net::UdpSocket;

const DATA: &[u8] = &[0; 1024];

fn main() {
    let time_start = SystemTime::now();

    let socket = UdpSocket::bind("192.168.1.155:1339").unwrap();
    for _ in 0..200000 {
        socket.send_to(DATA, "192.168.1.122:80").unwrap();
    }
    let elapsed = time_start.elapsed().unwrap();
    println!("Time {} ms to send 200 000 packets", elapsed.as_millis());
}
```

Avg. result (built in --release mode): `Time 1863 ms to send 200 000 packets`

For the Go benchmark, this is essentially the code:

```
var buff = []byte("")

func main() {
    buff = []byte(RandomString(1024))

    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen:", err)
    }

    loopSendHello(*conn)
    conn.Close()
}

func loopSendHello(conn net.UDPConn) {
    timeStart := time.Now()
    for i:=0; i < 200000; i++ {
        sendHelloEdited(&conn)
    }
    timeStop := time.Now()
    timeDelta := timeStop.Sub(timeStart)
    fmt.Println("Took", timeDelta.Milliseconds(), "ms to send 200 000 packets.")
}

// targetAddr is target address in form of net.UDPAddr
func sendHelloEdited(conn *net.UDPConn) {
    _, err := conn.WriteToUDP(buff, &targetAddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error while writing to conn! :", err)
    }
}
```

Go avg. result: `Took 1959 MS to send 200 000 packets.`

Now for the Python test, this is the code:

```
def main():
    x = 0
    data = random._urandom(1024)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    addr = (str(ip), int(port))
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    while x < 200000:
        s.sendto(data, addr)
        x += 1
    s.close()
    endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    deltaTime = endTime - startTime
    print("Took", deltaTime, "to send 200 000 packets")

main()
```

Interestingly the python result was always quick, with an avg. output of: `Took 0:00:01.831531 to send 200 000 packets`

So it seems Go is indeed slowest, but only marginally.

Comment: UDP on windows is mainly limited by call-overhead. That is why you don't see much difference. You must use "UDP segmentation" to get good UDP performance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-wsasetudpsendmessagesize